# Why is proguard not obfuscating anything?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my project in Android Studio by using proguard. But after compile nothing changes. When I decompile it it looks like nothing happened but shrink works. Why doesn't it work?

Gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
```

proguard-android.txt

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}


-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}"
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
    -ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Comment: Your `proguard-rules.pro` has `-keep class *`. That will keep all classes.

Comment: omg, you are right. Thank you man

Comment: Ivan Sablin, If this satisfies your question please select CommonsWares post as solution or CommonsWare make a answer instead of a comment so he can select as the answer.